# How to consume SOAP services in NestJS?

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, nestjs

I have to consume a SOAP service in NestJs for one of my projects. I am trying to consume a dummy SOAP service from web. Below are the details -

URL -

```
http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL
```

Method - POST

Headers -

```
Content-Type: text/xml
```

Request Body -

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <CapitalCity xmlns="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
            <sCountryISOCode>IN</sCountryISOCode>
        </CapitalCity>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Response Body -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <m:CapitalCityResponse xmlns:m="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
            <m:CapitalCityResult>New Delhi</m:CapitalCityResult>
        </m:CapitalCityResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I am not able to figure out how to consume this service in my NestJs dummy application. By exploring for quite sometime, I found a library nestjs-soap, which I installed and configured as mentioned below -

```
npm install nestjs-soap --save
```

My app.module.ts -

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SoapModule } from 'nestjs-soap';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    SoapModule.registerAsync([
      { name: 'MY_DUMMY_CLIENT', uri: `http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL` }
    ])
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My app.service.ts -

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Client } from 'nestjs-soap';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {

  constructor(@Inject('MY_DUMMY_CLIENT') private readonly myDummyClient: Client) {}

  getHello(): string {
    return process.env.APP_MESSAGE;
  }

  getDetails(): string {
    return process.env.APP_DETAILS;
  }

  asyncGetCountryCapital() {
    //this.myDummyClient.
  }
}
```

As the documentation I referred is not in detail, I am not able to figure out how to call the SOAP service within asyncGetCountryCapital() function.

Answer (score 1):

Today I needed to do the same thing and turns out that the documentation of `nestjs-soap` is not so clear.

After trying a few things, this is what worked for me.

### 1. Using *method*

The docs for this is [here](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientmethodargs-callback-options---call-method-on-the-soap-service).

#### Example without sending parameters

##### Module:

```js
SoapModule.register({
    clientName: 'CountryInfoService',
    uri: 'http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?wsdl',
})
```

##### Controller:

```js
import { Client } from 'nestjs-soap';

constructor(
    @Inject('CountryInfoService') private readonly soapClient: Client,
) {}

@Get('soap')
soap() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.soapClient.ListOfContinentsByName(null, (err, res) => {
            if (res) {
                resolve(res);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Notice the first parameter, I needed to pass `null` (can be `{}` too) because without it, I cannot declare the function in the second parameter.

Also, I have encapsulated it using `new Promise()` to be able to return it to the client.

#### Example sending parameters

##### Module:

Let's use another `uri` for this, this is the only one that I could found out there.

```js
SoapModule.register({
    clientName: 'NumberConversion',
    uri: 'https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?wsdl',
})
```

##### Controller:

```js
import { Client } from 'nestjs-soap';

constructor(
    @Inject('NumberConversion') private readonly soapClient: Client,
) {}

@Get('soap')
soap() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.soapClient.NumberToWords({ ubiNum: 235 }, (err, res) => {
            if (res) {
                resolve(res);
            } else {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Notice the first parameter, you need to pass an object with any properties you need.

### 2. Using *methodAsync*

The docs for this is [here](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#clientmethodasyncargs-options---call-method-on-the-soap-service).

#### Example without sending parameters

```js
@Get('soap')
async soap() {
    return await this.soapClient.YourFunctionNameAsync(null);
}
```

#### Example sending parameters

```js
@Get('soap')
async soap() {
    return await this.soapClient.YourFunctionNameAsync({a: 1, b: 'hi'});
}
```

The key here is to add the word `Async` at the end of your function name. Example, taking the function `ListOfContinentsByName` from before, the name will be `ListOfContinentsByNameAsync`.

--

I got this solution looking at the [nodejs soap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) library closely. The first example about how to use it, shows that you need to have a `client` function and a `method` function.

Then, looking at the code on GitHub of the [nestjs-soap](https://github.com/lehh/nestjs-soap) library, I saw that they are giving you only the `client` function, not both.

You/we need to provide the `method` function, example:

##### Using *method*

```js
// The second parameter as a function is the key
this.soapClient.YourFunctionName(null, (err, res) => {
});
```

##### Using *methodAsync*

```js
// Add the word `Async` at the end of your function name
const result = await this.soapClient.YourFunctionNameAsync({a: 1, b: 'hi'});
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: It not answer the question, this is the same as the documentation.  Im getting js error "is not a function", and cant figure out what to use like the guy in the question. Why it dont have something like "call/get/etc" where we can put the request directly, i dont have a function name, only the service url to send the xml, and it works from postman

Answer (score 1):

I found how to use it and is in the documentation. You need to call

this.soapClient.describe(), and in the response you have all the methods that the client allows.

:)